# There is no openssl.so extension with php7.2.x

Tags: php, linux, openssl

I am not good with php, and my customer complains that openssl.so is not under the extension_dir, i do not know if this is normal or not to not find  openssl.so under extension_dir, any reason for that ?

I have openssl installed,

i have also checked the below

[image]

[image]

[image]

`ls -la /usr/lib/php/20170718 |grep -i openssl`
and openssl.so not there, any idea what to do ?

i have also enabled openssl extension from php.ini as following then restarted apache

`vim /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`
[image]

i am using `php7.2.4 with Debian Jessie 8.6 and apache 2.4.10`

Comment: It's not an external extension, OpenSSL support is compiled into PHP core an uses the system's lib.

Comment: @Sammitch is there is any reference for that as i am frustrated from searching online

Comment: [Look in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php). I'm not sure what the issue is here, it looks like OpenSSL is enabled and should work fine. There's no earthly reason to need to know where the extension's `.so` file is.

Answer (score 4):

As i found that php7.x.x has openssl compiled within the php core and doesn't need an external extension to enable it

Answer (score 4):

there is some problem with openssl provided with php 7.1.x, but the problem is resolved at for php versions after 7.2.x as they have inbuilt openssl 1.1.1